# Troublesome Wice::WiceGridArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a Rails 3.1.1 app that is using WICE_GRID and I am stuck on this error.
I want to show a grid of Roles on the User show page. I am setting up the data in the controller like this.
User and Role are related by has_many through user_role.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @roles = initialize_grid(@user.roles)
end
```

When I run the site I get this error

```
Wice::WiceGridArgumentError in UsersController#show
WiceGrid: ActiveRecord model class (second argument) must be a Class derived from ActiveRecord::Base
```

The error is pointing to **@roles = init....** line. initialize_grid does take a record arguent but that is a hash of options, not an activerecord model collection. 
When I run the code in the console I see that @user.roles is

```
[#<Role id: 1, title: "Role1>, #<Role id: 2, title: "Role2">]
```

Looks like an ActiveRecord collection to me.

Any help gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize_grid takes a class.  You're passing in an array of objects.  It appears you want to display a user's roles in the grid.  You want something like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @roles = initialize_grid(Role, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', @user.id])
end
```

However, I'm guessing your roles table doesn't have user_id in it.  You likely have a mapping table called user_roles.  In which case, you will want to refactor the code above.  Try just running this code instead to make sure you can view Roles in a grid (unscoped).

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @roles = initialize_grid(Role)
end
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood how initialize_grid() works. Thanks for your help!